# Why can I drop a table when I am not owner of it neither a super user

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, only the schema owner, table owner, and super users should be able to drop a table but it seems I am able to drop one while being neither and I can figure out what I am missing.

I have two users, let's call them `database_owner` and `table_owner`.

The `database_owner` creates the database and then runs the following SQL to allow connection for the `table_owner` user:

```sql
GRANT CONNECT, CREATE ON DATABASE mydb TO table_owner;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO table_owner;
```

Then I log in with the `table_owner` user, create a schema, and run various migrations. Eg:

```
CREATE SCHEMA "my_schema";
CREATE TABLE "my_schema"."test_table" ("id" serial,"value" text);
```

At this point I verify that I am the owner of the object and I am logged in with the `table_owner` user:

```sql
SELECT current_user, session_user;
-- returns table_owner  table_owner

SELECT nsp.nspname AS object_schema,
       cls.relname AS object_name, 
       rol.rolname AS owner, 
       CASE cls.relkind
         WHEN 'r' THEN 'TABLE'
         WHEN 'm' THEN 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW'
         WHEN 'i' THEN 'INDEX'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'SEQUENCE'
         WHEN 'v' THEN 'VIEW'
         WHEN 'c' THEN 'TYPE'
         ELSE cls.relkind::text
       END AS object_type
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class cls
  JOIN pg_roles rol ON rol.oid = cls.relowner
  JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = cls.relnamespace
WHERE nsp.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
  AND nsp.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_toast%'
  AND rol.rolname = current_user  --- remove this if you want to see all objects
ORDER BY nsp.nspname, cls.relname;

-- returns
-- my_schema    test_table_id_seq   database_owner  SEQUENCE
-- my_schema    test_table          database_owner  TABLE

SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name, pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS owner
FROM   pg_namespace n
WHERE  n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER  BY 1;
-- returns
-- my_schema    database_owner
-- public       azure_superuser
```

Then I move back to the `database_owner` user and verify that I am not a super user and I am the database owner:

```sql
SELECT current_user, session_user;
-- returns database_owner database_owner

SHOW IS_SUPERUSER;
-- returns off

SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
WHERE d.datname = 'test'
ORDER BY 1;
-- returns database_owner
```

Now I try to delete my table and I succeed.

```sql
DROP TABLE "my_schema"."test_table";
-- returns Query 1 Ok: DROP TABLE
```

What I am missing? Does the database owner has full access to all objects in the database even when no privilege is granted?

Answer (score 0):

The database owner does not automatically have permissions to drop a table in the database, nor does the schema owner. You can drop a table only if

- you are a superuser
- you are the owner of the table, or you are directly or indirectly a member of the owner of the table

Since you say that `database_owner` is not a superuser, it must be a member of `table_owner`. The only other explanation could be that you are not really using PostgreSQL, but a fork where the permission system has been hacked up.